# How to retrieve all subdomains of my domain with PHP

Tags: php, dns, subdomain

They are dynamically created subdomains. I don't know the names and how much they are, I need to loop the domain to get all the subdomains so I it's something like

```
foreach domain as subdomain{
 // do something
}
```

could it be done with PHP?

Comment: How are they created ?

Comment: Have you tried to parse '/etc/hosts' file? Which OS using the server?

Comment: @Dagon Wordpress `*.example.com`

Comment: Your PHP application will need to be configured somehow so that it knows what subdomains are routed through it. Could you provide more information about your application's software stack, @JigongBagong?

Comment: I'd rather not to configure anything, because it'll touch the core of Wordpress, I just need to add a function. so I thought it could be retrieve from `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` or other built in server function

Comment: Unless you're allowed to do a zone transfer, DNS offers no access for this type of request. You can test with `dig @yourdnsserver rootdomain.com axfr`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been 2 days, so the conclusion is, there's no way to do this with PHP for now.

For all, if you landed here with the same problem, Try to retrieve Multisite Wordpress sub-domains *automatically* with PHP, you can forget it, **for now** you should handle all the sub domain *manually*.